# RMS velocity of a gas vs RMS velocity of a gas molecule, which is a more appropriate term?

Tags: velocity, ideal-gas

I'm a bit confused by the terminology. Is it the RMS velocity of a gas, or the RMS velocity of the gas molecules or of a gas molecule?

Similarly, is it the mean velocity of a gas, or the mean velocity of the gas molecules or of a gas molecule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the molecules which have the velocity not the gas as a whole.

The RMS velocity of the molecules in a gas (mean taken at an instant of time) should be the same as the RMS velocity of a gas molecule (mean over a "long" period of time) but given the qualification (and uncertainty) regarding the length of time go for *The RMS velocity of the molecules in a gas*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer sir!

Answer (score 1):

The **RMS velocity of a gas** is the square root of the arithmetic mean of the squares (a particular [generalised mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean)) of its *molecules' **instantaneous** velocities*.